# Firebreath NPAPI plugin rendering video to top level browser window (HWND)

Tags: plugins, browser, npapi, firebreath

I am working on a audio/video rendering plugin that is using FireBreath and we have a need to get HTML elements to overlay on top of the video. I am aware that to do this I need to use the  windowless mode in FireBreath. However since I am using DirectX to render the video I cannot initialize DirectX with the HDC handle (it requires a HWND) that I get when I am instructed to render in windowless mode.

Also for other software security reasons I cannot render the video to an off-screen surface then Blt the bits to the HDC.

The alternative I was trying to accomplish is to use the Hardware Overlay feature in DirectX and use the browser's TOP level HWND to initialize DirectX, then use the HDC and coordinates to tell directX where in the TOP browser window to render the video frame. And render it directly to the top parent browser window.

I have tired a proof of concept, but I am seeing my video frames getting erased quite often after I draw them and thus the video appears to be flickering. I am trying to understand why that might be and I am wondering if this is not a viable solution given my parameters.

Also I am wide open to suggestions on how to accomplish this given my constraints.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @taxilian Hope you can help shed some light on this! Thanks!

Comment: It would really be better if you posted this only in one place, instead of in three places.  I will copy and paste my other response to you into here, but next time please only ask once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the FireBreath-dev group, John Tan wrote:
>
> As what I know, you practically have no control precisely when the screen is going to draw. What can only be done is:
>
> 1) Inform the browser to repaint by issuing the windowless invalidatewindow
>
> 2) browser draw event arrives with the hdc. Draw on the hdc

John is completely correct.  In addition, the HDC could potentially (perhaps likely will) be different each time your draw is called.  I don't know of anyone who has successfully gotten directx drawing using windowless mode, and you have absolutely no guarantee that what you are doing will ever work as even if you got it working the browser may change the way or order that it draws in in a way that would break it.

You might want to look at the async surface API; I don't know which browsers this works on but I suspect likely only Firefox and IE.  It was implemented in [this commit](https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/commit/caf3403eb3fc1ec01cb475d9b8f7b21d1459ee87).

I haven't used this at all, so I can't tell you how it works, but it was intended to solve exactly the problem you're describing.  Your main issue will be browser support.  [What documentation there is is here](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/Windows+Asynchronous+Surface+Rendering).

Hope this helps